# ChartJS how to sync animations when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I need help trying to sync the animations so they all start and end together. Another thing is it seems like a few charts are larger when I initial load the page and causes things to jump around any idea on how to keep them the same dimensions so there isn't anything funky going on.

Video: https://youtu.be/xVjnnToZbdA
Code: https://github.com/ItIsN3RD/StackOverflow/blob/main/Charts.php

Comment: Use `window.onload` event listener and then initialize chart.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of some custom styles and how to display multiple charts using chartjs version 3.5.1
Example:
https://github.com/ItIsN3RD/StackOverflow/blob/main/Charts.php